# How to make this collapsible panel start off collapsed without onLayout delay?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This works and all, but it calculates height with `onLayout` so it does this thing where it has to start off expanded to get the height, then quickly collapses. On slower phones it can't happen fast enough and looks pretty bad. I tried hiding the collapsible part while it calculates but am having trouble making this smooth.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import {
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Animated,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native'
import {
    Icon,
} from 'native-base';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

class Panel extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        expanded: PropTypes.bool,
    icon: PropTypes.string,
        title: PropTypes.string,
        onToggle: PropTypes.func,
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        expanded: false,
    }

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        expanded: props.expanded,
        animation: new Animated.Value(),
      };
    }

    toggle = () => {
        const { onToggle } = this.props;
        const { expanded, maxHeight, minHeight, animation } = this.state;
    const expandedHeight = minHeight + maxHeight;
    const collapsedHeight = minHeight;
        const initialValue = expanded ? expandedHeight : collapsedHeight;
        const finalValue = expanded ? collapsedHeight : expandedHeight;
    const animationType = 'spring';  // spring, timing

        this.setState({ expanded: !expanded });
        animation.setValue(initialValue);

        Animated[animationType](animation, {
            toValue: finalValue,
        }).start();

        onToggle();
    }

    _setMinHeight(event) {
        const { minHeight, expanded, animation } = this.state;
        if (!minHeight) {
            this.setState({ minHeight: event.nativeEvent.layout.height });
            if (!expanded) {
                animation.setValue(event.nativeEvent.layout.height);
            }
        }
    }

    _setMaxHeight(event) {
        const { maxHeight } = this.state;
        if (!maxHeight) {
            this.setState({ maxHeight: event.nativeEvent.layout.height });
        }
    }

    render () {
        const { expanded, animation, maxHeight } = this.state;

        return (
            <Animated.View style={[styles.container, { height: animation }]}>
                <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#C7CAEE" onPress={this.toggle}>
                    <View
                        style={styles.titleContainer}
                        onLayout={event => this._setMinHeight(event)}
                    >
            {this.props.icon && <Icon style={styles.titleIcon} name={this.props.icon} />}
                        <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</Text>
                        {this.props.filtering && <Icon style={styles.filteringIcon} name="md-funnel" />}
                        <Icon style={styles.toggleIcon} name={expanded ? "ios-arrow-up" : "ios-arrow-down"} />
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <View
                    style={styles.body}
                    onLayout={event => this._setMaxHeight(event)}
                >
                    {this.props.children}
                </View>
            </Animated.View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    margin: 5,
    overflow:'hidden',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderColor: '#C7CAEE',
        borderWidth: 1,
  },
  titleContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  titleIcon: {
    color: 'black',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    color: '#2a2f43',
    fontWeight:'bold',
  },
  toggleIcon: {
        color: '#E91F63',
        paddingRight: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  filteringIcon: {
        color: '#3F51B5',
        paddingRight: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        fontSize: 20,
  },
  body: {
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: 0,
  },
});

export default Panel;
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.container, { height: animation }, { opacity: (minHeight && maxHeight) ? 1 : 0 }]}>
```

Looks alright, but there's gotta be a better way to do this! Also the animation skips on really long lists of items...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could try is **LayoutAnimation**, which interpolates between the previous and next states of your UI. Instead of `Animated.View` you'd use a regular `View` and switch between `{ height: 0 }` and an unspecified height, letting the layout system compute it for you.

To animate the height change, call `LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut()` before `setState` calls that collapse or expand the UI.

---

If you wish to try an approach using `onLayout` but without a flicker, you can try setting the panel's opacity to zero while measuring it, or positioning the panel absolutely so it doesn't affect the layout of its surrounding components while you measure it.

You also can apply these techniques to ancestor components of the panel. For example, you could set the whole screen's opacity to zero while measuring the panel.